# How to handle route param updates in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

If the destination is the same as the current route and only params are changing

```
going from one profile to another /users/1 -> /users/2.
```

How can I recognize this and update the component?

Comment: if you are using the route param in the component already, it will automacally be updated

Comment: nuxt will automatically take care of this. You need not explicitly do any logic (like introducing "watch" as descibed in answer below). it was required in vuejs routing but not in nuxt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure its the same for next.js but in due router even if the parameter changes the same component is reused. So you need to specifically `watch` the param changes.

From Vue router Documentation:

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.

Take a look here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes